# Как проверить listbox на добавленный элемент?

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При добавлении нового элемента в listbox, который находится слева, в textbox должны добавляться 20 очков. Как проверять listbox на любой новый элемент?

Comment: Просто храните данные в нормальной коллекции, а не в контроле, он предназначен для отображения, а не хранения

Comment: Каким образом происходит добавление элементов в ListBox? Вот там, где вы пишете `listBox.Items.Add(...)`, там же добавьте изменение значения в текстбоксе.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю класса listbox, но сомневаюсь, что подобный функционал в нём существует. listbox это массив с своей функцией, создайте массив `List<bool> NewConstructor` с необходимой для вас функцией новизны.

Comment: На заметку: в дотнете есть коллекции [ObservableCollection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) и [BindingList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?view=netframework-4.8), которые имеют события добавления элементов.